# Python split() for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I try to insert some value from the database from the dictionary and it works fine but it inserts value in this format ex. `"S"` instead of `S`.

I try to use function `split()` as in example:

```
cat_sName = dumps(item_meta_data[int(menu_item.id)]['short_name'].split('"'))
```

and when I print cat_sName it print this value:

`['', 'S', '']` instead of `S`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `strip` instead of `split` to get rid of the quotation marks:

```
>>> '"S"'.strip('"')
'S'
```

Where do they come from originally?

Comment: thank you it works fine with strip()

Answer (score 3):

You should use `strip()` function to remove the double quotes:

Like this

```
cat_sName = dumps(item_meta_data[int(menu_item.id)]['short_name'].strip('"'))
```

`strip` function removes stuff whereas `split` function splits the string into an list based on the delimiter.You should strip to do removal jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
cat_sName = dumps(item_meta_data[int(menu_item.id)]['short_name'].split('"')[1])
```